# Zulkarnain is Jesus, is it possible

Tags: prophet-isa

Salam, How Allah prescribed zulkarnain means 'the posesser of two age (qarn-ain) alternatively karn, and qarn can also means horn but I prefer age because when Allah talk about him Allah mention time along-side-with-it.

So I do have this question, could it be possible that Jesus is actually him because in surah al-kahf Allah do mention about 'people of the cave' that connected to our time in term of protection of imaan.

Comment: No, dhul qarnian lived during Abraham's time and youths in the cave came after Jesus.

Comment: The stories of Jesus and Zul-Qarnain are worlds apart

Answer (score 1):

You mean Zulkarnain and Jesus is same person. If it was your question it is wrong. Jesus(pbuh) is a Prophet and also son of the Virgin Mary(pbuh) and Zulkarnain is a king who built a wall to stop Ya'jooj and Ma'jooj.

Answer (score 1):

First, "Zulqarnain" means "2 horns".

Traditionnaly, this person, is considered to be Iskander, AKA Alexander the Great, known to be the greatest conquerer of all the time.

If you look at the representation of king Alexander the Great by his people, he was represented with 2 horns (see [here](http://www.stephenricker.com/study/daniel/alexander_coin_horn.jpg))

There's no mention of horns about Jesus/Isa.

It could take several pages to explore, but what the Quran says about Zulqarnain is the same thing that is said in history and greek tales about Iskander/Alexander.
.

> Alexander said, "This mountain is higher and more terrible than all
>   the mountains which I have seen." The old men, the natives of the
>   country, said to the king: "Yea, by your majesty, my lord the king,
>   neither we nor our fathers have been able to march one step in it, and
>   men do not ascend it either on that side or on this, for it is the
>   boundary which God has set between us and the nations within it"
>   Alexander said, "Who are the nations within this mountain upon which
>   we are looking? "The natives of the land said, " They are the Huns."
>   He said to them, " Who are their kings?" The old men. said: "Gog and
>   Magog..." Alexander said to the natives of that country," Have they
>   come forth to spoil in your days?" The old men answered and said to
>   the king: "May God establish thy kingdom and thy crown, my lord the
>   king! These fortresses which have been overturned in our lands and in
>   the lands of the Romans, have been overthrown by them; by them have
>   these towers been uprooted; when they go forth to spoil, they ravage
>   the land of the Romans and of the Persians, and then they enter their
>   own territory."

Comment: What traditions consider "Alexander" to be Zul-Qarnian? Any Islamic references?

Comment: What is acceptable as islamic reference?

Comment: Any reference from the Quran or the Sahih Hadiths. Thank You.

Comment: Hadiths can't use the word "Alexander" as it is a translation. It's a circular logics, like asking me to show you where sahih use the word "Jesus". Is there a sahih that call "Isa", "Jesus"? Read the islamic text describing the story of this man, and then, read the Greek sources, and compare.

Comment: There is well known parallel between Dhul Qarnayn and syriac Alexander legend (Neshana) - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_Alexander_Legend

Answer (score 0):

Walekum Salam
When Zulqarnain is mentioned, he is mentioned as an explorer. There were two known and great explorers around that time and it's possible that Zulqarnain was also known as Cyrus (the explorer) and the horns could be his halmet like the Vikings etc.

I got to this answer through own research on google so could be wrong. As the other was Alexander the great but he was after Cyrus I think and his timings are perhaps more closer to those events.

Wallaho alam

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] check the [help] to learn more about this site. I strongly suggest you to elaborate your answer by adding some references to support your claims and read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

No he is not. Jesus (PBUH) is a prophet and not an explorer/king who travelled around the world with his army.

There are many propositions for the identity of Zul-Qarnain, notably Cyrus, Alexander and an Egyptian Pharaoh. I personally dismiss Alexander completely since he wasn't that benevolent ruler described in Surat Al-Kahf.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our [tour] and visiting our [help].

Answer (score 0):

Zul Qarnain was actually Cyrus The Great. I used to held the view that it was Alexander, but upon thorough research : comparing and contrasting like:

1. Cyprus The Great defeated the Babylonians and funded and rebuilt the Temple of Solomon.
2. Cyprus The Great promoted Judaism and was even praised by the Jews in their holy books.
3. His era or timing actually concedes with Prophet Ibrahim (A.S). There is a narration that they both met on hajj (yet to confirm it authenticity)....

Unlike Alexander who was:

a) a homosexual
b) an Idolator, believing in the Greek gods. He was NOT a Muhlis (Monotheist)

I finally made such conclusion - wal Lohu a'lam....

Comment: Cyrus live around 600 BC which is long after Ibrahim. According to historians he was a pagan too.